# TooManyRequestsException: Rate exceeded while adminCreateUser

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-serverless

In pre-signup lambda function I'm trying to create user through `adminCreateUser`. But signup is taking longer time than my expectation. My other code such as `adminGetUser`, `ListUser`,`adminDeleteUser`  are working very well. But this is taking longer time & throwing `TooManyRequestsException`.

**MY FUNCTION :**

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const cognito = new aws.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({apiVersion: "2016-04-18",});

exports.handler = async (event, context,callback) => {
    const EMAIL = event.request.userAttributes.email;
    const cognitoParams = {
        UserPoolId: event.userPoolId,
        Username: event.userName,
        MessageAction:"SUPPRESS",
        ForceAliasCreation:true,
        TemporaryPassword: "Pass@123",
        UserAttributes: [{
            Name: "email",
            Value: EMAIL,
        },
        {
            Name: "email_verified",
            Value: "true",
        },
        ],
      
    };
    let response = await cognito.adminCreateUser(cognitoParams).promise();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
    callback(null,event);
};
```

**CLOUDWATCH LOG :**

```
2022-08-22T05:16:40.444Z    XXXXXXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX   ERROR   Invoke Error    {
    "errorType": "UserLambdaValidationException",
    "errorMessage": "PreSignUp failed with error PreSignUp invocation failed due to error TooManyRequestsException..",
    "code": "UserLambdaValidationException",
    "message": "PreSignUp failed with error PreSignUp invocation failed due to error TooManyRequestsException..",
    "time": "2022-08-22T05:16:40.400Z",
    "requestId": "XXXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXXXXX",
    "statusCode": 400,
    "retryable": false,
    "retryDelay": 52.896734522859056,
    "stack": [
        "UserLambdaValidationException: PreSignUp failed with error PreSignUp invocation failed due to error TooManyRequestsException..",
        "    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)",
        "    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)",
        "    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)",
        "    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)",
        "    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
        "    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
        "    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
        "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
        "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:12)",
        "    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Pre sign-up Lambda trigger documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html):

> Shortly before Amazon Cognito signs up a new user, it activates the
> pre sign-up AWS Lambda function. As part of the sign-up process, **you
> can use this function to perform custom validation** and, based on the
> results of your validation, **accept or deny the registration request**.

You are not supposed to create the user as part of the lambda code, just run some verifications to accept or deny the creation.

The call to `adminCreateUser` will also invoke the Pre sign-up Lambda, so, with the code you have provided, you are creating an infinite loop of calls between `adminCreateUser` calls and the lambda:

SignUp -> preSignUpLambda -> adminCreateUser -> preSignUpLambda -> adminCreateUser -> preSignUpLambda -> ...

Until you reach the point of too many calls to `adminCreateUser` ([50 req/s](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html)) and it fails, without any user creation as none ever completed.

In case you are trying to confirm the user and verify the email as he signs up, there's a similar [example in documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html#aws-lambda-triggers-pre-registration-example-2):

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    // Confirm the user
    event.response.autoConfirmUser = true;

    // Set the email as verified if it is in the request
    if (event.request.userAttributes.hasOwnProperty("email")) {
        event.response.autoVerifyEmail = true;
    }

    // Return to Amazon Cognito
    callback(null, event);
};
```

If you actually need to create an **additional** user, different from the one signing up (where the at least the `userName` needs to be different), make sure to flag it somehow so that it doesn't loop. A good way would be to create using a custom attribute, and only call `adminCreateUser` if the attribute isn't present.

Comment: What is the solution?

Comment: Just updated the response with the solution for confirming the email, if that's what you were trying to achieve.